# Angular.js и React.js

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

Как могу исползовать *React.js* с **Angular** для рендеринга больших дата листов(ng-repeat).

 Так как рендеринг *React.js* работает на неськолко раз быстрее чем у Angular.
 А проект стоит на Angular и сменить все на React это самоубийсто :)

Answer (score 1):

Необязательно использовать ng-repeat. Можно посмотреть в сторону таких решений:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/
В которых НЕ используется deep watch, значит и не будет обновления всего списка при изменении какого-то из внутренних значений элемента коллекции.